# Copy one array's value to second array's value continuously

Tags: javascript, arrays, onchange

I have a requirement that one array is copied continuously to second array if first array's value is changing.

Suppose there are two arrays array1 and array2, and if array1 value is changing then array2 must be changing as per array1.

So keeping `array1` and `array2` same.

Thanks

Comment: And why not just have one array, if they're always supposed to be the same ?

Comment: Why not simply ensure that array2 is the same as array1 just before array2 is to be used somewhere?

Comment: Actually i have one array of angularjs and another was plain javascript. So when angular array is changing then also javascript array change.

Comment: Still, just use the same array.

Comment: Is it possible or not? Let me know.

Comment: Just try using one array, okay? It's easy

Answer (score 1):

Array is an object in javascript which means you assign reference instead of value

```
a = array();
b = a;
```

Then both b and a contains the same array. Adding value to the a will add it into b as well.

```
a.x = 5;
alert(b.x); //will show 5
```

---

If you really need two different arrays, you may try to play with [getter/setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters). But not sure how exactly it should work in your case.